# Phase Transitions of Purified Proteins

Tags: proteins, biophysics, protein-binding

Why do solutions of purified protein condense into droplet phases?

I'm trying to understand the protein phase transitions.

Here is the article http://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(12)00634-4#

It's on Intracellular Granules as Liquid Droplets

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE! Thanks for your question... it always helps if you can give some additional information so others can understand what you're asking. Also, links embedded in the question that re-direct to other sources may be helpful as well.